# React hook setState arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to know the difference between the following two versions of  code. Both versions do the same.

1) Here just the *counter* variable is used to get the current value

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  return <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>{counter}</button>;
}
```

2) This version passes a function to *setCounter*

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  return <button onClick={() => setCounter(c => c + 1)}>{counter}</button>;
}
```

The official documentation says:

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a
>   function to setState. The function will receive the previous value,
>   and return an updated value.

So what's wrong with the first option? Are there some pitfalls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the particular code in your example, you have the previous value in hand, so there isn't much difference. But sometimes you don't. For example, suppose you wanted to have a memoized callback function. Due to the memoization, the value of `counter` gets locked in when the closure is created, and won't be up to date.

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  // The following function gets created just once, the first time Counter renders.
  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCounter(c => c + 1); // This works as intended
    //setCounter(counter + 1); // This would always set it to 1, never to 2 or more.
  }, []); // You could of course add counter to this array, but then you don't get as much benefit from the memoization.

  return <button onClick={onClick}>{counter}</button>;
}
```